# What is the design pattern behind this code in Java?

Tags: java, class

why are there classes, my question is not with the specifics but the design pattern. What design pattern is this? Why is the class returning itself?

```
public class Baseline implements PTSD
{

  public static class BaselinePTSDFactory implements PTSDFactory {

    public Parser getParser(List<Tree<String>> trainBees) {
      return new BaselinePTSD(trainBees);
    }
  }

 // .... Many Functions and Data Structures

}
```

Comment: You're not posting enough code, including interfaces to tell, but I'm guessing that it might be the abstract factory pattern (assuming abstract class/interface somewhere)

Comment: And the class isn't "returning itself". It has a static method that creates an instance.

Answer (score 1):

## Java Tree Design Pattern

From what I can find I believe the design pattern for your code segment is **Composite Design Pattern**.

"Composite design patterns describe groups of objects that can be treated in the same way as a single instance of the same object type. The composite pattern allows us to "compose" objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies."

Answer (score -1):

Capturing as to what each pattern does or used for. Work on to validate for appropriate implementation from source with complete code against each of the pattern.

Source Code: https://github.com/DINESHLOMTE/designpatterns

***Creational Pattern:*** Defines the best possible ways using which objects can be created or instantiated.

Types of Creational Patterns:

- Factory Pattern
- Abstract Factory Pattern
- Singleton Pattern
- Builder Pattern
- Prototype Pattern

---

**Factory Pattern:** Is used in case if there is a base class and n number of derived classes and based upon the data you pass one of the object of the derived class needs to be returned.

---

**Abstract Factory Pattern:** Adds a layer of abstraction higher than the factory pattern, Unlike Factory pattern returns one of the instance of the derived class abstract factory return such a factory which can be further used to process one of the instance of the derived class.

---

**Singleton Pattern:** Enables to have a single instance of a class at the application level.

---

**Builder Pattern:** Enables to build complex objects from simple ones step-by-step, doing so it separates the construction of the complex objects from their representation.

---

**Prototype Pattern:** This implies cloning of the object to avoid creation. If the cost of creating new object is high and creation leads to resource intensive, we clone the object using the Cloneable interface clone() method to do so. Once after cloning two identical objects of the same type will be existing in the memory.

---

***Structural Pattern:*** describes how objects and classes can be combined to form larger structures. It is important to understand the difference between the class and object pattern. Class pattern defines abstraction with the help of inheritance and how they can be used to provide more useful program interfaces, while Object pattern defines how objects can be associated and composed together to form larger and more complex structures.

Types of Structural Patterns:

- Adapter Pattern
- Bridge Pattern
- Composite Pattern
- Decorator Pattern
- Façade Pattern
- Flyweight Pattern
- Proxy Pattern

---

**Adapter Pattern:** Defines how to make two unrelated interfaces or components work together. The joining between them is called as adapter. This is something like converting the interface of one class into the interface as expected by another client.

Adapter Pattern can be implemented in two ways, by Inheritance and by Composition

---

**Bridge Pattern:** Enables to separate out the interface from its implementation. Doing so, it gives the flexibility so that both the implementations can vary independently.

---

**Composite Pattern:** During the development of an application we may come across the components having individual objects and also can be collection of objects. Composite pattern enables to deal with this condition/situation. In turn composite pattern enables to develop a tree structure in order to represent part-whole hierarchies.

---

**Decorator Pattern:** Enables to add behavior or responsibilities to an object. This is also called as Wrapper. Suppose we have 6 objects and 2 of them needs a special behavior we can do this with the help of decorator.
Decorator pattern can be used where-ever there is a need to add functionality to a object or group of objects.

---

**Façade Pattern:** Acts as a single point of entry to access the sub system components.

---

**Flyweight Pattern:** Defines a mechanism to avoid the creation of large number of object instances to represent the entire system.

---

**Proxy Pattern:** Enable to create the complex object from the simple one. If the cost of creating the object is expensive and its creation can be postponed till the time it is actually needed, till than a simple object can be used, this simple object is called as proxy representing the complex one.

Types of Proxy Design Pattern:

- **Remote Proxy:**
  Is responsible for encoding a request and its arguments and for sending encoded requests to the real subject in a different address space.
- **Virtual Proxy:**
  Is a place holder for expensive to create object. The real object is created only when it is actually needed means only on the first request of the object.
- **Protection Proxy:**
  Checks or validates if the caller has the required privileges or permission to perform such request.

---

***Behavioral Pattern:*** Is concerned about interaction between the objects. The interactions between the objects should be such that both the objects are talking to each other but still they are loosely coupled. Loose coupling is the key in n-tier architectures. In this, the implementation and client should be loosely coupled in order to avoid any hard coding and dependencies.

Types of Behavioral Patterns

- Chain of Responsibilities Pattern
- Command Pattern
- Iterator Pattern
- Interpreter Pattern
- State Pattern
- Strategy Pattern
- Visitor Pattern
- Template Pattern
- Observer Pattern
- Mediator Pattern
- Memento Pattern

---

**Chain of Responsibility Pattern:** It decouples the sender of the request to the receiver. The only link between the sender of the request and the receiver is the request sent. Based on the request sent the receiver is picked. This is called as data-driven concept. Most of the behavioral patterns are based on the data driven concepts, data driven concepts enables to have loose coupling.

---

**Command Pattern:** The client sends a request; this request is propagated as a command. The request maps to particular modules. According to the command, a module is invoked.

---

**Iterator Pattern:** Enables to iterate through the collection of elements without need for knowing the underlying implementation.

---

**Interpreter Pattern:** Enables to elevate language, syntax or expressions. This involves implementing an expression interface which tells to interpret a particular context.

---

**Strategy Pattern:** Defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each one of them and makes them interchangeable. In turn it lets algorithm vary independently from the clients that use them.

---

**State Pattern:** Enables to manage algorithms, relationships and responsibilities between the objects. This is a clean way for an object to partially change its type at runtime.

---

**Visitor Pattern:** Defines a mechanism to separate out an algorithm from the object structure on which it operates. Doing so it provides the ability to add new operations to the existing object structures without modifying those structures.

---

**Template Pattern:** Defines a program skeleton of algorithm in an operation, wherein it defers the implementations of certain steps to derived classes, so that the derived class can provide the implementation without changing the algorithms structure.

---

**Mediator Pattern:** Enables to deal with the complexities that come with coding when number of classes increase. It makes the code more maintainable and promotes loose coupling, such that only one class mediator has the knowledge of all classes while rest of the classes have their responsibilities and they only interact with mediator.

---

**Memento Pattern:** Defines a mechanism or provides an ability to restore an object to its previous state.
Memento pattern is implemented with three objects: the originator, a caretaker and a memento itself. Originator is some object that has the internal state. The caretaker intends to something to the originator but wants to be able to undo the changes. The caretaker first asks the originator for a memento object and then it does whatever it intends to do. To roll back to the state prior to the change it returns the memento object to the originator. The memento object itself is a kind of opaque object, which the caretaker cannot or should not change. When implementing this pattern care should be taken if the originator may change other objects or resources. The memento pattern operates on a single object.

---

**Observer Pattern:** Is used when there is one-to-many relationship between the objects such that if one object is modified its dependent objects are to be notified automatically.